# Controlling on tap text large size in flutter bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter's bottom navigation bar. On tapping the navbar icons, the text get larger. But it's way bit large for me as you can see in the image below.
[Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsgQC.jpg)

I want to control the on tap text large size and make it a bit smaller. How can I do that in flutter?

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:adminify/pages/PageOne.dart';
import 'package:adminify/pages/PageTwo.dart';
import 'package:adminify/pages/PageThree.dart';
import 'package:adminify/pages/PageFour.dart';
import 'package:adminify/pages/PageFive.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void navigationTapped(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = page;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this is all pages here in list we can choose index when click bottom navigation bar
    List<Widget> _allPages = [
      PageOne(),
      PageTwo(),
      PageTree(),
      PageFour(),
      PageFive(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: _allPages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }

  // Bottom navigation bar area you can choose icons what you want.
  BottomNavigationBar buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      fixedColor: Colors.red,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      onTap: navigationTapped,    
      // iconSize: 28,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text(
            "Home",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.explore,
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Admission",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cloud),
          title: Text(
            "University",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text(
            "Favorites",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),      
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a property `selectedFontSize` on the `BottomNavigationBar`.
You can use this one. Simply set the size (interger) to the desired value.

Additionaly; there is also a unselectedFontSize on the `BottomNavigationBar`, ther you can set all the title-fontsize attonce to the desired size.

```
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12,
        unselectedFontSize: 12,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                color:
        omitted ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check the source code of the `bottom_navigation_bar.dart`, you will see that the active font size of the bottom navigation bar is fixed, it is written as follows:

```
const double _kActiveFontSize = 14.0;
```

if you want to change this, I think you need to create your own custom bottom navigation bar to the active font size that you want.

Answer (score 0):

From having a short look into the BottomNavigationBar code, you can't. It seems that it uses the hardcoded `_kActiveFontSize` which is set to `14`. Check `bottom_navigation_bar.dart` line 366 for `FixedLabel` style or line 411 for `ShiftingLabel` style. You may want to create an issue to get that fixed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues